# How to isolate plots per day from dataframe?

Tags: r, loops, plot, dataframe

I have the following `data.frame` with a lot of rows:

```
> head(data09)
     No       Date         Time Close   Volume Weekday            DateTime
61 3421 03.12.2012 09:00:00.000 7.430 39000000  Montag 2012-03-12 09:00:00
62 3422 03.12.2012 09:01:00.000 7.429 41000000  Montag 2012-03-12 09:01:00
63 3423 03.12.2012 09:02:00.000 7.428 42000000  Montag 2012-03-12 09:02:00
64 3424 03.12.2012 09:03:00.000 7.430 35000000  Montag 2012-03-12 09:03:00
65 3425 03.12.2012 09:04:00.000 7.430 30000000  Montag 2012-03-12 09:04:00
66 3426 03.12.2012 09:05:00.000 7.432 36000000  Montag 2012-03-12 09:05:00
>
```

It basically shows tick minute data over a long time. If I want to have a plot of the first day I can get it with:

```
plot(data09[1:453,7],data09[1:453,4],type="l",xlab="time",ylab="value")
```

This gives the following plot:

[image: tete]

So this is for Monday the 03.12.2012. Now I want to have a plot for each day and save it to my disk. How can I get this? I do not know how to tell R to do it per day, so it would have to search in the Date column for the same day. The data range is from 03.12.2012 up to 13.12.2013 and I want to have saved a plot for each day to my disk. And one further thing: It would be great, if there could be a mark in the name of the file, showing the date. So e.g. 03122012.png and 04122012.png and so on.

My data is [here](http://www.qfpost.com/file/d?g=dFed1bHEO).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP is asking for a plot saved to a separate png file for each day:

```
plot.day = function(df) {
  filename = paste0(df$DateTime[1]$mon+1, df$DateTime[1]$mday, df$DateTime[1]$year+1900, ".png")
  png(filename)
  plot(df$DateTime, df$Close, type="l", xlab="time", ylab="value")
  dev.off()
}

by(data09, data09$Date, plot.day)
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I get the following:

Fehler in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
Zusätzlich: Warnmeldungen:
1: In min(x) : kein nicht-fehlendes Argument für min; gebe Inf zurück
2: In max(x) : kein nicht-fehlendes Argument für max; gebe -Inf zurück

Comment: There are some plots saved to my disk, but a lot of days are missing?

Comment: I know what the reason could be: The DateTime column was not created correctly, according to your post here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723182/plot-of-minute-tick-data-with-correct-x-axis-formatting I used data09$DateTime = strptime(paste(as.character(data09$Date), as.character(data09$Time)), "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S") but for some days this leads to NA values in the column DateTime ?

Comment: E.g. if you look at the following entry: data09[50000,] This is the 29.07.2013. Every column, especially the column date and time has an entry. But when I enter strptime(paste(as.character(data09[50000,2]), as.character(data09[50000,3])), "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S") this gives a NA value. Why, where is my mistake? Or why is your command you said I should use not working in this case?

Comment: Compare it to: strptime(paste(as.character(data09[20000,2]), as.character(data09[20000,3])), "%m.%d.%Y %H:%M:%S")

 Here it works and a value results.

Comment: Ah I know, damn! This is german formatting, so the day comes first! So it should be "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S" right??

Answer (score 1):

For example , you can use `by` to split by the column Date:

```
by(data09,data09$Date,function(dat)
    plot(dat[,7],dat[,4],type="l",xlab="time",
         ylab="value"))
```